# In a for loop how to send the i few loops back upon a condition

Tags: python, for-loop

is there any way to send the value of a for look back in few loops..

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    if random.randint(0,9) in [5,6]:
        i = 0
```

what i want to do is exactly something like this. now here i know the range(10) generates the range [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] first the then traverse it by assigning the value to i. so simply changing the value of i will not work.

but is there any other way to change i in a way that the value in the next loop will i+1

Comment: seems only using while loop can be achieved what you wants.

Comment: What output are you actually trying to get?

Comment: @Sayse I don't think the output is actually significant here - it could be the numbers 0 - 9 or an infinite output, or somewhere in between... I think the OPs is using it as an example of the kind of control flow they'd like to achieve

Comment: what i am trying to do is something completely different from this code.. i just wrote this so that its easy to read.. i just didnt think of a while loop in this case.. i will use a while loop and i think i can get my function to work

Comment: put please.. let me know if it is possible to achieve using a for loop too

Comment: all three of these answers are the same.. sorry guys.. but i think i am gonna wait for someone to do it will a for loop.. if possible. i already wrote the while loop by my self..  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
import random
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    if random.randint(0,9) in [5,6]:
        i = 0
    else:
        i +=1
```

Edit: my bad, it won't work indeed, `while` loop will.

Comment: this will not work, since in the next loop yield i will be reassigned

Comment: yes.. this is not going to work.. but i think i got the idea.. i can do what i want using a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `for` loop, you can do a `while` loop by declaring `i` outside the loop.

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    if random.randint(0,9) in [5,6]:
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
```

With this, and a bit of tweaking, I think you can get the result you wanted.